# I am implementing single Linked List using Rust but I am getting issue while I am trying to print values of the linked list using display method

Tags: rust, linked-list

I have implemented Linked List program in rust with following  Node struct and LnkdList struct.But when i am implementing the display method in LnkdList struct I am getting an error in the while loop at current = &node.borrow().next.Compiler is telling ->temporary value dropped while borrowed

[image: This is the error message that Rust compiler is showing]

Below is the code for Linked List

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Node<T> {
    val: T,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T: std::fmt::Debug> Node<T> {
    fn new(elem: T) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            val: elem,
            next: None,
        }))
    }
}

pub struct LnkdList<T> {
    head: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    tail: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    size: i32,
}

impl<T: std::fmt::Debug> LnkdList<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        LnkdList {
            head: None,
            tail: None,
            size: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn add_front(&mut self, data: T) {
        let new_head = Node::new(data);
        match self.head.take() {
            Some(old_head) => {
                new_head.borrow_mut().next = Some(old_head);
                self.head = Some(new_head);
            }
            node => {
                self.tail = Some(new_head.clone());
                self.head = Some(new_head);
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn add_back(&mut self, data: T) {
        let new_node = Node::new(data);
        match &self.tail {
            Some(node) => {
                node.borrow_mut().next = Some(new_node.clone());
                self.tail = Some(new_node)
            }
            none => {
                self.tail = Some(new_node.clone());
                self.head = Some(new_node);
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn display(&self) {
        let mut current = &self.head;

        while let Some(node) = current {
            println!("{:?}", node.borrow().val);
            current = &node.borrow().next;
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented the LnkdList program  as follow

```
fn main() {
    let mut list = lnkd_list::LnkdList::new();

    list.add_front(1);
    list.add_front(23);
    list.display();
}
```

I expect that the out put should be 23,1 but display method is throwing error as described above

Comment: Please include error messages / compiler output as text in the question, not as a screenshot. Also, you may like [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Comment: Don't learn Rust by implementing a linked list, that's just a bad idea. It won't teach you good or idiomatic Rust, it'll just confuse you. And if you must, please check out the tutorial @Brian61354270 mentioned. Also, why abbreviate names like `LnkdList`? There is no longer a limitation for identifier names in programming languages.

Comment: Also, it's `None` with capital `N`, not `none`. And definitely not `node`! (in the match arms).

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this error is fairly simple. The error says that you cannot drop the guard for the `RefCell` while you're using it. But since it's a `Rc` anyway, you can just clone it:

```rust
pub fn display(&self) {
    let mut current = self.head.clone();

    while let Some(node) = current {
        println!("{:?}", node.borrow().val);
        current = node.borrow().next.clone();
    }
}
```